# Docker : multiples linked containers for each customers

Tags: mongodb, docker, haproxy, devops, parse-server

I'm developing a platform that monitor emails, save the results in a Mongo database (through Parse-Server) and display the results on a web app (using AngularJS).

Basically, for each customer i want a SMTP server, a Parse Server, a MongoDB & a web platform.

I thought of using Docker for more scalability and the idea is to automatically create the containers when the user signup on my website but I don't really understand how to link these containers together : web1|smtp1 connected to parse1 connected to mongo1 & web2|smtp2 connected to parse2 connected to mongo2.

In the end, i want the customers to access the web app through web1.website.com, so I think i should also use Haproxy..

I'm just wondering if it's really the best way to do it as i'm going crazy with the automation process and if you have any tips to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using Docker (specifically Docker Compose) linking containers together is very easy. In fact it happens out of the box! If you compose all your containers at the same time, a Docker network is created for your "composed app" and all containers can see each other.

See the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

> Each container can now look up the hostname web or db and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, web’s application code could connect to the URL postgres://db:5432 and start using the Postgres database.